# Aggregating rows in dataframe with another aggregated rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Following is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {"uid": ['1','2','3','','3','','4','5'], "pid":['a','b','a','d','c','e','','']}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data
```

[image]

Now when i group my dataframe based on UID and aggregate the data of grouped rows. So that I get the following output.

[image]

Notice here i don't want the rows with uid = "" to be grouped together.

Now i want to group by above dataframe let's say **temp** dataframe on PID so that i get the following output:

[image]

Notice how UID of 1 and 3 is grouped because they had 'a' as common in UID, inspite of PID = 3 having one more element in its UID column. And while grouping rows with pid = "" are also not grouped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems networkx graph problem for find groups by `uid` and `pid` by common values:

```
data = {"uid": [1,2,3,'',3], "pid":['a','b','a','d','c']}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)

import networkx as nx

# Create the graph from the dataframe
g = nx.Graph()
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(data,'uid','pid')

connected_components = nx.connected_components(g)

# Find the component id of the nodes
node2id = {}
for cid, component in enumerate(connected_components):
    for node in component:
        node2id[node] = cid + 1

data['g'] = data['uid'].map(node2id)
print (data)
  uid pid  g
0   1   a  1
1   2   b  2
2   3   a  1
3       d  3
4   3   c  1
```

---

```
df = data.astype(str).groupby("g").agg(lambda x: '|'.join(x.unique()))
print (df)
   uid  pid
g          
1  1|3  a|c
2    2    b
3         d
```

EDIT:

```
data = {"uid": ['1','2','3','','3','','4','5'], "pid":['a','b','a','d','c','e','','']}
data = data.replace('', np.nan)

data = pd.DataFrame(data)

#filter only non missing values in rows
mask = data.notna().all(axis=1)

data1 = data[mask].copy()
print (data1)
  uid pid
0   1   a
1   2   b
2   3   a
4   3   c
```

---

```
import networkx as nx

# Create the graph from the dataframe
g = nx.Graph()
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(data,'uid','pid')

connected_components = nx.connected_components(g)

# Find the component id of the nodes
node2id = {}
for cid, component in enumerate(connected_components):
    for node in component:
        node2id[node] = cid + 1

data1['g'] = data1['uid'].map(node2id)
print (data1)
  uid pid  g
0   1   a  1
1   2   b  2
2   3   a  1
4   3   c  1
```

---

```
data1 = data1.astype(str).groupby("g").agg(lambda x: '|'.join(x.unique()))
print (data1)
   uid  pid
g          
1  1|3  a|c
2    2    b

#add original rows with missing values
df = pd.concat([data1, data[~mask]])
print (df)
   uid  pid
1  1|3  a|c
2    2    b
3  NaN    d
5  NaN    e
6    4  NaN
7    5  NaN
```

Comment: Hi @jezarel thanks a lot for the quick response. But i have edited my question can you please check once.

Comment: @aman - Not understand, if not groupby why are finally instead `''` value `4` ? What does mean not groupby ? It means if change first 1 to `''` finally there should be only `3` instead `1|3` ?

Comment: @jezarel I have changed the example for better understanding. Please take a look.